# how to control concurrent mappers in HBase

Tags: java, hive, hbase, hadoop-yarn

I have a import job into hive external table (Hbase). As my data is too large and I see 500 mappers are opened and being executed. But i want to control the number of concurrent mappers needs to be executed simultaneously.

My expectation is. 
Let hive still create 500 mappers. But I want only 100 mappers should be executed at a time.

Not sure how to control the concurrent mappers.

Any help really appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I have tried this option and worked for me. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5583

Answer (score 0):

> My expectation is. Let hive still create 500 mappers. But I want only 100 mappers should be executed at a time.

Not sure what is meant by this. But if you are looking to control the number of mappers, one way is to control the input splits as below:

```
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize= <some number>;
set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize= <some number>;
```

Setting the max and min size of input will help you in controlling the mappers.

Also you can try setting the number of mappers in hive:

```
SET mapreduce.job.maps=100
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the info Rishu. This one (set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize= <some number>;) split the file based on the numbe we set, and for each split one mapper will be assigned. And all the mappers starts running simultaneously. But I am looking for solution like, let it create mappers based on the number of splits. But i dont want all of them to run simultaneously.  For example 100 mappers are created based on the splits. But I want only 10 of them should run at a times. once those 10 completes then it will take next 10 for execution. Hope I explained little bit clear now.